# Python3, OpenCV and C#

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, opencv, ironpython

I'd like to port my current python3 project with the use of opencv, numpy to Windows and integrated with C# projects. However, I found that IronPython only supports up to Python2. A few issues:

- What is the best way to do the integration as the python code depends on a number of external libraries and python3 wrapper?
- What is the way to integrate with C# if IronPython3 is not yet ready?

Comment: I am in your same situation. For now my advice is to learn C#. I am doing this right now and I found out it's a beautiful language. Also,OpenCV exist also for C# with the name EmguCV.
This said, if you know the logic of your project (which should be obvious), a port should not be too difficult.

Comment: I cannot change the source code that is already in python3. And also another C# project is already ready for integration. I am looking for an integration solution.